# Web app showing user profile using his user_id or using a uuid

Tags: security, web-applications, user-profile

I'm developing a Web App with Grails. My Web App has users who have profiles. When I want to view someone's profile I have two options: use the userid (which is sequential and can be guessed) or create a uuid field in the user profile and index it, so when a link is generated for a user, the uuid is as a part of it, the servlet can read the uuid params and find the user for it.

This is my initial idea of not exposing userid since they are sequential and guessable. I just don't want somebody write a for loop and replace the value of the userid and pull all profiles. The link is something like this:

```
Non-Secure with profile id:
www.xyz.com/profile/user/123

Secure with uuid:  
www.xyz.com/profile/user/550e8400e29b41d4a716446655440000
```

Is there a better way of securing this or is what I'm doing is reasonable enough to stick to ?

Comment: Is the userid the only unique column? Do you have a unique username column?

Comment: username isn't unique. and email is unique but I don't wanna expose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UUIDs are unique, and if you generate one for each user, it obviously would not be guessable for which user the key belonged to.

However, UUIDs are calculated, and are typically incremental. They are not random. Hence, they can still be guessed somewhat. Try generating a series of UUIDs on the same machine (immediately after another) and you will notice that a large portion of the numbers are identical. In fact, if all of the UUIDs are generated on the same machine, you may as well remove the machine id portion of the UUID to save space.

If you generate the UUID on the client side, at least they will vary more because the machine ID portion will be different for each one.

Consider, instead, hashing the email address plus the userid. SHA1 creates a hash which is only (in hexadecimal form) 8 bytes longer (40 bytes) than your UUID example (32 bytes).

If you really wanted to, you could check for duplicates when generating the hashes, but if you find a collision in SHA1, I think you win a prize. Well, at least you'll be famous, and I'll say, "I knew you when...".

Comment: Thanks Marcus, good answer. But can't they decrypt the SHA1 and retrieve the user email address ? I know that MD5 is broken, not sure about SHA1. So what you suggest is not to use the UUID or if I use it I better remove some repetitive stuff from it such as machine id and etc. So if I generate 2 uuid in 24 hours interval, are they still gonna be the same or the duration between the creation is varying ?

Comment: You can't decrypt a hash. You could use [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) if you're still concerned about attacks.